# Delete all spaces and tabs around point in intelliJ?

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea, pycharm

In emacs, there's an action called `just-one-space` which is binded to <kbd>Meta+Space</kbd>.

It is used to

> Delete all spaces and tabs around point, leaving one space (or N
>   spaces).

I used this action a lot in emacs and it's quite useful for me.

I was wondering whether there are also such actions in intelliJ?

(The use case is like this:

```
      Line1
      Line2
```

when I use <kbd>Ctrl+k</kbd> at the end of Line1 twice, the text becomes this:

```
      Line1                Line2
```

I need several actions to delete the spaces to make it like this:

```
      Line1 Line2
```

Comment: Can you provide the use case? May be **reformat code** action can replace it?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for your suggestion. I added the use case in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found that `Join Lines` might be what I need.

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ can use regex, so

```
Search: \b\s+\b
Replace: <space>
```